# Mostrar resultados de una consulta a la BD en diferentes INPUT text

Tags: php, html, mysql, jquery, input-type

estoy realizando un programa de administración de pacientes el cual busca guardar en una nueva tabla en la BD los valores dados por una consulta realizada en MySQL desde mi código PHP. Soy algo nuevo en la programación en php y no he logrado mi objetivo.

Logre realizar la consulta de la base de datos, al obtener estos valores me gustaría poderlos mostrar en un input text cada valor. Intente con este código pero no funciono al momento de hacer la inserción de este dato a mi input text. Lo requiero en un input text para que pueda agregar estos datos a mi nueva tabla de BD.

```
            <?php
        include ("datos.php");
        $con = mysqli_connect($host,$usuario,$clave,$base) or die("No se conecto a la BD") or die("Problemas al conectar server");

            if(isset($_POST['Consultar'])){  //
            mysqli_select_db($con,$base)
            or die ("problemas al conectar db");
            $registro= "SELECT * FROM datospaciente WHERE ID_Expediente_Paciente ='$_POST[Id_Expediente_Paciente]'";

                            if ($resultado = mysqli_query($con, $registro)) {

                                        /* obtener array asociativo */
                                        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)) {

                                        $Id_Paciente= $row['Id_Paciente'];
                                        $ApPaterno= $row['Apellido_Paterno'];

                                        }
                                          mysqli_free_result($resultado);
                                        }
            }
```

Este es mi código HTML, solo anexo una parte debido a que este es muy extenso.

```
<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars(  $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])?>" method ="post">
        

        <table style="width:0%" bgcolor="D7E6F0"> 
            <tr>
         <th> <li >His </li> </th> 
         <th> <input type="text" name="His" id="His">  </th>
         <th> <li >Id Expediente del Paciente </li> </th> 
         <th> <input type="text" name="Id_Expediente_Paciente" id="Id_Expediente_Paciente">  </th>
         <th><input type="submit" name="Consultar" id"Consultar" value="Consultar"></th>
                        <tr>
         <th> <li>Nombre del Paciente </li></th> 
             <th> <input type="text" name="Nombres_Paciente" id="Nombres_Paciente">  </th>
        
         <th> <li>Apellido Paterno del Paciente </li></th> 
             <th> <input type="text" name="Apellido_Paterno" id="Apellido_Paterno" value="<?php echo $row['Apellido_Paterno']?> ">  </th>
            
 
/* tambien intente con <?php echo $ApPaterno?> */

         <th> <li>Apellido Materno del Paciente </li></th> 
             <th> <input type="text" name="Apellido_Materno" id="Apellido_Materno">  </th>
            </tr>
```

Estuve buscando Y se que se debe hacer con jscript . Intente hacerlo funcionar con este codigo, pero no logre hacer que la variable pase con la información.

```
            <script type='text/javascript' src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>



                <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function()
                {
                $("#Consultar").click(function () {
                //saco el valor accediendo a una variable que proviene de la base de datos ApPaterno y lo asigno a uno con name = Apellido_Paterno 
                $("#Apellido_Paterno").val($("$ApPaterno").val());
                });     
            });
            </script>
```

Si alguíen me podría orientar con este problema de como se imprime una consulta de datos a un input text lo agradacería.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disculpa; no entendí bien tu código. Más que nada el inicio y fin del **PHP**; te comento considerando lo que entendí.

**PHP** como sabes es un lenguaje que se ejecuta en el servidor; de tal que ya sea uses [`print_r`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.print-r.php), [`echo`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.echo.php),... o de la forma que lo generes para devolverlo en respuesta a la ejecución del **.php** invocado/llamado: tal que, lo básico es:

```
<?php
 /* Aqui tu código */
?>
```

Ahora, como tienes (así lo "veo") mezclado **PHP** y **HTML**; tienes que usar la apertura y cierre de PHP (es decir `<?php /* código */ ?>` cada vez que ejecutaras código PHP); ahora bien, usando parte de tu código:

```
<?php
include ("datos.php");
$con = mysqli_connect($host,$usuario,$clave,$base) or die("No se conecto a la BD") or die("Problemas al conectar server");

if(isset($_POST['Consultar'])){  //
    mysqli_select_db($con,$base)
    or die ("problemas al conectar db");
    $registro= "SELECT * FROM datospaciente WHERE ID_Expediente_Paciente ='$_POST[Id_Expediente_Paciente]'";

    if ($resultado = mysqli_query($con, $registro)) {
?>
<!-- Cerramos código PHP, ponemos HTML con PHP -->
<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars(  $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])?>" method ="post">
    <table style="width:0%" bgcolor="D7E6F0"> 
<!-- Abrimos de nuevo PHP -->
<?php
    /* obtener array asociativo */
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)) {

?>
<!-- Cerramos código PHP, ponemos HTML con PHP -->
        <tr>
            <td><li >Id Expediente del Paciente </li></td>
            <!-- El siguiente TD tiene HTML y PHP
            <td><input type="text" name="Id_Expediente_Paciente" id="Id_Expediente_Paciente" value="<?php echo $row['Id_Paciente']; ?>"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><li>Apellido Paterno del Paciente</li></td>
            <!-- El siguiente TD tiene HTML y PHP -->
            <td><input type="text" name="Apellido_Paterno" id="Apellido_Paterno"  value="<?php echo $row['Apellido_Paterno']; ?>"></td>
        </tr>
<!-- Abrimos de nuevo PHP -->
<?php
        }
        mysqli_free_result($resultado);
    }
?>
    </table>
</form>
<?php
}
```

Espero no haber dejado abierto o mal cerrado alguna parte del código.
Ahora bien te sugiero dar una leida a TAG `Table` para que distingas cuando se usa el `TH` y cuando el `TD` (se usan dentro de `TR` cuyo padre sea 'thead' y `tbody` respectivamente).

Comment: Muchas gracias el código fue de mucha ayuda para mi solo falto mover algunos } para que funcionara correctamente, respecto a mi codigo en el post menciono que son solo fragmentos del código que es la función que realiza el select debido a  esto es que en la primera parte se corto el final de <?php ?>  por este motivo no se ve completo debido a que tenia otra consulta debajo de este codigo. Respecto a las tablas gracias por la observación, me falta estudiar esta parte y ahora veo mi error en las tablas. Agradezco el tiempo que te tomaste para responderme. Gracias, un saludo.